# How to bind textbox text to 'current' item of collection

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I'm new to WPF and been trying to sort this out all day:

I have a list with six public properties (read about wpf only binding to public properties).

In my mainwindow I have two controls; a datagrid with three columns, and three textboxes.  I wish to databind the three datagrid columns to three properties of my List, and databind the remaining three properties of my List to the textboxes (one property per textbox).  The datagrid databinding works fine:  `myDataGrid.ItemsSource = myList; 
//specific column binding is in xaml as expected eg
 Binding="{Binding Title, Mode=TwoWay}"`

The trouble is with the textboxes.  I intend for the textboxes to display the 'current item' in the underlying List, meaning that as the user selects different datagrid rows the textboxes should change to show the values of data bound properties of the 'currently selected list item'.  Simply binding the texboxes like this is not doing the job:

```
Text="{Binding SomePropertyName}"
```

I have read about using CollectionViewSource in order to facilitate 'current item' pointers using the forward slash in the xaml bindings, but had no luck there either ie

`<Textbox Text="{Binding Path=/someProperty}"`

I've also read about people databinding to the datagrid / listview items using 'elementname' bindings but this is not what I'm after.  Should be quite easy I think, at least in winforms it was!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite easy, but there's one thing to be aware of. You can select more than one line in a `DataGrid` by default and in that case, only one value will show in the textbox. You can change this by setting `SelectionMode="Single"` on the datagrid.

```
<StackPanel>
    <DataGrid x:Name="PersonsGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="First name" Binding="{Binding FirstName}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last name" Binding="{Binding LastName}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Age" Binding="{Binding Age}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

    <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Address, ElementName=PersonsGrid}" />
</StackPanel>
```

This works because `SelectedItem`'s underlying type is `Person` in my example.

Comment: Thanks Ondrej, works great much appreciated.  Thanks also for the 'SelectionMode' tip as well.